# IIS 7 Grant folder access

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, iis-7, permissions

I get the following error:

```
ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access 
rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process 
identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6) that is used   
if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via 
<identity impersonate="true"/>, the identity will be the anonymous user (typically 
IUSR_MACHINENAME) orthe authenticated request user.
```

I have read that there is no ASPNET user in IIS 7. I have also added [Machine name]\IIS_IUSRS but still get the error. Which user do I need to add?

Answer (score 1):

Try IIS APPPOOL[apppoolname_without_spaces].
In IIS7 all your apppool work under AppPoolIdentity. For example Default App Pool will have user IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool.

Comment: It says it's running under Network Service, which I gave full control too and I also gave Everyone full control too (for testing), but still get the error. To I need to restart the pool?

Comment: Hm, can you try to go to advanced apppool settings and check if Load user profile is set to true? I remember getting errors with certificate private key access without this stuff turned on.

Comment: under the app pool, it says 0 applications for my site (WebVTS) though, why is that?

Comment: Can you check in which apppool you app runs?

Comment: DefaultAppPool - I tried to make it an application, but now I can see I get this error: The server is configured to use pass-through authentication with a built-in account to access the specified physical path. However, IIS Manager cannot verify whether the built-in account has access. Make sure that the application pool identity has Read access to the physical path. If this server is joined to a domain, and the application pool identity is NetworkService or LocalSystem, verify that <domain>\<computer_name>$ has Read access to the physical path. Then test these settings again.

Comment: You cant transform apppool to app=) in advances settings of you app(not apppool) change apppool to WebVTS.

Comment: app pool is set to webvts, still denied